# Strategies to cue client requests when offline

Tags: javascript, cordova, vue.js, offline, service-worker

### Context

A mobile client web application (html/js) that makes PUT http requests to a tracking endpoint. The application is built on top of cordova, using vuejs vuex, superagent and localforage

### Problem

When the client is offline the requests end up with a timeout and the information to transport is lost.

I think the next step is to cue the requests, my question is where does this logic belongs.

Explaining this same problem I've been told that this should be implemented on **service workers**, but reading about it I don't see any benefit from using that, since the client app does not rely on the response using things like a cached response won't solve my problem.

On the other end I think this could be achieved by storing on the device the cue of requests and delete once its sent successfully to the server.

### Question

1. Is there any recommendation, or good practice to follow regarding this problem?
2. Should this be implemented on service workers or in the application itself?
3. Are there any libraries that tackle this same problem?

Comment: Don't think this deserves an answer on its own, but the thing you're looking for is `backgroundSync` in service workers. A great write-up is on PonyFoo: https://ponyfoo.com/articles/backgroundsync

Comment: Thank you for the reference. Effectively that was implicitly mentioned in @niladri answer `self.addEventListener('sync', fn)`. The article does help to understand the all idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach should be to store the data in local memory ie `cache or IDB` then register a `sync event` in `serviceWorker`. So that, when your app is online again that `sync` event will take care of that task.

Here's an example:

Inside the application from where you want to store:

```
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && 'SyncManager' in window) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready
      .then(function(sw) {
        var post = {
          data: 'Some Data'
        };
        writeData('sync-posts', post)     //save in local storage
          .then(function() {
            return sw.sync.register('sync-new-posts');
          })
          .then(function() {
            // display that post was saved for background sync (purely optional)
          })
          .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
          });
      });
  } else {
    sendData();     //in-case browser is incompatible
  }
```

Inside the `serviceWorker` do something like this:

```
self.addEventListener('sync', function(event) {
  console.log('[Service Worker] Background syncing', event);
  if (event.tag === 'sync-new-posts') {
    console.log('[Service Worker] Syncing new Posts');
    event.waitUntil(
      readAllData('sync-posts')     //reading from local storage
        .then(function(data) {
          // upload the data & free up the storage
        })
    );
  }
});
```

Tool for managing `ServiceWorker`: [WorkBox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/)

Comment: This looks good ;) A doubt, the application will store the events in whatever available storage (this is where the cue is created) then the service worker reads from the storage once the sync event is triggered (when the user has a stable connection), after this occurs who is responsable to delete that item(s) from the storage?

Comment: Oops! Forgot to mention that, `serviceWorker` should clean up the storage as soon as it is done with it.